# What is the effect of x=x++;?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x=100;
  x=x++;
  printf("x : %d\n",x); //prints 101
  return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for output 101? I think output should be 100.

Comment: This smells like undefined behavior.

Comment: It should be 101, you are mistaken

Comment: I wish all questions on SO have that many answers :)

Comment: It should be 101.  Try "printf("x : %d\n",x++)" instead of "x=x++" if you want 100.

Comment: It *is* undefined behavior?  Check accepted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: @maverik - I'd settle for one right answer rather than seven wrong ones, though.

Comment: I think it should be drop-kicked into the next county.

Comment: Can't believe this *weekly* question has got so many wrong answers.  `x = x++;` This invokes **undefined behaviour** in C.
The important thing to note here is that the assignment operator ( `=` ) *doesn't* introduce a sequence point. So whether the incremented value is assigned to `x` or old value of `x` is assigned to `x` can't be deduced correctly as `x` is being modified twice without an intervening sequence point in the expression `x = x++`.

Comment: @KingsIndian "weekly" only if you spend too much time elsewhere. Almost daily.

Comment: @DanielFischer hehe... May be I am not active enough to predict the frequency of this question accurately ;-) Nice to your your shadow face :)

Comment: @KingsIndian - You can spend all day waiting for a language lawyer, then five come round at once ;-) SO's problem is the increasing number of bad questions make it almost impossible to find the nuggets.

Answer (score 6):

This is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), due to [Sequence Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx).

> Between consecutive "sequence points" an object's value can be
>   modified only once by an expression

The end of the previous epxression `x=100;` is one sequence point, and the end of `x=x++;` is another.

Basically, your expression has no intermediate 'sequence points', yet you're modifying the value of X twice. the result of this is Undefined Behaviour: Basically, *anything* could happen: You could get 100, 101 or 42...

Comment: I think you're right?  I suspected it but didn't investiage.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: @John - Thanks. I've flagged this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I believe you're looking for:

```
int main(){
    int x=100;
    printf("x : %d\n",x++); // Will print 100 and then increment x
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But in Java, this program's output is 100. Value is assigning before increment. But why is it change here??

Comment: @ThisaraRanawaka C is not Java - different rules are in place here.

Comment: @Reed - So what's the "Rule" here, then? why *isn't* this UB?

Comment: There was a comment (I don't know why author deleted it) and it said that increment goes first and then assignment (due to operators priorities). Isn't that right?

Comment: If this is correct, what does `x = 2 * x++;` do, and why?

Comment: @Roddy: The result of `x=x++` *is* undefined - 6.5.2/2: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undeﬁned."  Both the `=` and `++` have side effects (assignment and increment, respectively), and they are not sequenced relative to each other (it's not guaranteed that the assignment happens before the increment).  The result will vary based on compiler, platform, surrounding code, etc.

Comment: @JohnBode - Thanks for confirming! Please vote to close before we get any more wrong answers...

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `x` before printing it - so this is the reason for the output `101`.

You're doing the same operations as `x = x; x++;`

Comment: But `x++;` would do the same thing.  Or is `x = x++;` the same thing as `x++;  x = x;` ?

Comment: @John It's more like the other way around - `x = x; x++;` - the assignment is basically "thrown away" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `x`  after assigning it to `x`, effectively:

The `x=x++` effectively becomes `(assign x to x prior to increment) then (increment x)`

This is going to give the same effect as if you were to wrote:

```
x = x;
++x; // Increment after the assignment
```

This should leave x as 101 after the `x=x++;` line.

Comment: Shouldn't the lines be the other way around?  Postincrement has higher precedence than assignment?

Comment: @John Yes... But the value is returned prior to the incremented value being set (hence **post**-increment), so the assignment happens prior to the increment.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the same `x` you're printing - here it doesn't matter whether post- or pre-incrementing.

`x=x++` would produce the same result as `x=++x`.

If you would like to assign it another object do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        int x=100;
        int y=x++;
        printf("y : %d\n",y); //prints 100
        printf("x : %d\n",x); //prints 101
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x=100;
  x=x++; // This is original code however I have rewritten this as below 
  x=x;
  x++;
  printf("x : %d\n",x); //prints 101
  return 0;
}
```

as you can see

```
x=x++;
```

can be rewritten as

```
x=x;
x++;
```

hence the result no surprises ...

Answer (score 0):

The effect is that the value of x won't change.

`x++` works like this:

1. Take a reference of the value.
2. Allocate a new integer and store the value into it.
3. Increment the reference.
4. Return the temporary integer.

In C++ it would look like this:

```
int PostIncrement(int& x)
{
    int y = x;
    x = x + 1;
    return y;
}
```

The operator precedence is not lost in this way and the assignment is done after the increment.

Comment: The order of operations is not guaranteed.  6.2.5/3: "The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.85) **Except as speciﬁed later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced.** 86)"  It's possible for the assignment to be sequenced before the increment; it's also possible for the assignment to be sequenced after the increment.  The result will vary from compiler to compiler (or for the same compiler with different optimization settings).

Comment: @JohnBode This is correct. In most commonly used implementations the order is as I have described.

Comment: `int& x` is a syntax error in C.